# Replacement of $this->element() CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

We all knew that `$this->element()` is deprecated. And they say, `The "$options['plugin']" is deprecated and will be removed in CakePHP 3.0. Use "Plugin.element_name" instead.`. So, what will be the replacement when I'm using it from a view not from a plugin? Or using `$this->element()` from view isn't deprecated.

Should I use the function from view?

Answer (score 5):

The `element()` method itself is not deprecated, only the use of the `plugin` key in the `$options` array. This means you should use

```
$this->element('Contacts.helpbox');
```

instead of

```
$this->element('helpbox', array(), array('plugin' => 'Contacts'));
```

See also http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#requesting-elements-from-a-plugin

Comment: `Should I use the function from view?`

Comment: Yes, it is intended to be used from views.

Answer (score 1):

Only the use of `plugin` key in `$options` is deprecated as like dhofstet said above.

To render element in plugin you can use this

```
$this->element('Contacts.helpbox');
```

**(OR)**

You can also render the element by setting 
`$this->plugin = pluginname` and then `$this->element('element_name)'`

i.e.

```
$this->plugin = 'Contacts';
$this->element('helpbox');
```

this will render the `helpbox` element in `Contacts` plugin